# How to find fundamental period of summation function?

Tags: summation

> I cant seem to understand how to find the fundamental period from this exponential function.
> $$\large x(t)=\sum _{k=2}^{k=14} e^{  j k\frac{2\pi}{7}  t}$$

I'd really appreciate any help, I cant find much anywhere

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: What would you get with $\sum^{k=14}_{k=1}$?  What is the difference?

Comment: I assume $j$ is an integer. Of course, if $j$ is a multiple of seven, then $x(t)$ is just the constant $13$.

Comment: Oh @GerryMyerson I am assuming that $j=\sqrt{-1}$ ...

Comment: Of course, I should have seen that (but mathematicians usually use $i$ for that, not $j$).

Comment: I suspect this is from an engineering book.

Comment: Is $x(t)=-\exp{\frac{2\pi j}{7}t}$ when we add up the GP?

Answer (score 0):

Let $w=\exp{\frac{2\pi j}{7}}$. Then
$$x(t)=\sum_{k=2}^{14} w^{kt}.$$
Replacing $t$ by $t+7$ leaves every term unchanged and so $x(t+7)=x(t)$.

Does that answer your question?